# Should I put my images inside the JAR or leave them out of it ? (Inno Setup)

Tags: java, text, installation, inno-setup, exe

So I have made a simple game using Java. I have my Jar file and inside it I am keeping my pictures. It's like a lot of pictures going on there. Like 140+ pictures at around 9 MB (mostly icons) (Not worried about efficiency, game already runs pretty smoothly). Now I wrapped my jar file into an .exe and then used Inno Setup to make a setup file. The thing is I am creating a folder in Program Files that only has a the application.exe file and the uninstallation file. This looks a bit vague to me and unprofessional. Though I've seen great games having all of their icons outside of the executable of course, just wondering would it be a good practice to keep the images inside or out ?
Suggestions are welcomed :D

Comment: Well if you're making an exe, they pretty much have to be out. Most games in this sense have the images out, but have a shortcut to the .exe instead so it doesn't look unprofessional

Comment: @Treyten I didn't go into deep research about this but I guess 'big' games keep images and other data out cuz it would not be practical to have an exe of 500MB or even more. Anyway I wanted some opinion on the issue and I think I got an answer for this issue. thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep images and other resources inside the JAR file. You don't want the user to change any of them, same as for the program classes. So I don't see why you should have a different storage for images compared to classes.

The most robust and simple (and that should be the meaning of "professional") setup is to have the whole program with all its prerequisites in just one file - either it's there and works, or it's missing, and you'll see that immediately. No need to check for existence and accessibility of dozens of subdirectories and files.

And as you're asking the question, you surely managed to read the images from the classpath, thus allowing to store them together with the class files, e.g. in a JAR.

Regarding wrapping in an EXE, that shouldn't make a difference: if the ClassLoader finds the classes, it'll surely find the images the same way. And even Ahead-Of-Time-Compilers support `getResourceAsStream()` (we've done that with Excelsior Jet).

Comment: "the whole program with all its prerequisites in just one file"- I'm kinda ambiguous with the sentence. I feel like the program should definitely be just one file as well but what if putting everything in one file results in an extra large file at a worst case scenario -supposing there are many many pictures and data in there.Well the "it's either works or is missing thing" also gets me thinking cuz I can change or delete some files inside the Photoshop folder in Program Files  and it would most probably do some damage :/ yet appreciate your answer but I'll wait and see some other opinions